# How to center align the title and buttons inside a modalDialog in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I tried the following which centers the action button only:

```
modalDialog(
    style = "text-align:center;",
    title = div("Welcome!", style = "text-align: center;"),
    
    shinyWidgets::actionBttn(inputId = ns("start"),
               label = "Start",
               style = "jelly",
               color = "danger")
)
```

This is inside a module. The title and 'Dismiss' `modalButton` are left and right-aligned respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the buttons, but for the title and text you can use `align = "center"`:

```
modalDialog(
    align = "center", # center the dialog text
    title = div("Welcome!", align = "center"), # center the dialog title

    shinyWidgets::actionBttn(inputId = ns("start"),
           label = "Start",
           style = "jelly",
           color = "danger")
)
```